# How to get rid of this weird angle?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I just downloaded blender a few hours ago, and while following a tutorial I somehow did this:

[image: donut project where icing is smooth but has a strange jagged edge]

I just started using the platform, so I have no idea how to fix this and make it smooth, like the rest of it. Can anyone tell me what I need to do? I tried moving the effected vertices (sorry if that's the wrong term) around and that didn't work, and that's about all I could think of doing. It has happened several times around the base of this mesh.

Comment: It looks like you were too harsh when you pulled the edge down with random proportional editing. You could try (in edit mode) select all > mesh (at the top of the window) > clean up > merge by distance. A little box will pop up in the bottom left - you might have to increase the value a bit to make them merge. Can't guarantee this will work though, because with the subdivision surface on, it's hard to see where the vertices actually are.. Are you using a solidify modifier as well?

Comment: please show the wireframe or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/